# Windows can't click inside certain windows

Tags: windows-7, window, blocking, mouse-click

So I've had this bug for a while, but it's getting more and more annoying...

It's the bug, that prevents me from clicking on windows. When I'm hovering over a button on the blocked program, I can see it change, as it normally would, but when I click on it, nothing happens, just like something was in the way.

Firstly, I've had problems with old Minecraft launcher, which was fixed after I updated Java from 7 to 8, but there are other programs, which aren't working and aren't written in Java, AMD CCC for example, so Java's probably not the cause. I'm also having problems with IntelliJ programs, which can't be clicked as well.

Also, I've been having problems with the fullscreen overlay block, which blocks the whole screen, until I do CTRL + ALT + DEL and then press CANCEL two times.

I've read on the forums, that the cause could be GPU drivers and/or network drivers, but I just reinstalled Windows 7 yesterday and the problem is back.
I've also installed Malwarebytes to scan the system, but it comes back as clean.
Also, I have disabled UAC(if that's in any way relevant).

My specs (if needed):

- CPU: FX-8320E 3.8GHz
- GPU: HD 7950 3GB
- RAM: 16GB Corsair RAM
- OS: Winblows 7 Ultimate
- Corsair SSD 275GB
- 12TB of HDDs

Does anyone have any idea about what could be causing this behaviour and how to fix it?

Comment: After you reinstalled Windows 7, what other applications have you installed?

Comment: @harrymc I've installed Discord, Chrome, MCP-HC, Vivaldi and Malwarebytes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say your copy of Win7 is faulty.  Try to reinstall the system from a different copy. 
If the problem persists, I'd move on to test the hardware.

1. Install the system on a different/new harddrive and test again.
2. Check the PSU cables
3. Try on a different motherboard with the same harddrive and test again.

Point is, something is faulty. If you are sure the software is ok, then move to the OS and after, the hardware.

Comment: That's a good point, the only problem could be in the original Win7 DVD... I'll try that, other than that, I'm afraid I can't do much. No spare parts, as far as PSU, HDD and/or motherboard... I'll try reinstalling from downloaded version, flashed on USB. Thanks!

Comment: If a USB pen drive is all you have, you can also try to prepare it with Hiren's boot and run mini windows xp from it. Muck around a bit on it. If nothing happens you found your problem.    https://www.hirensbootcd.org/

Comment: I have Hiren's boot cd already on anither DVD... Let me try that. :) thanks

Comment: ......Any luck?

Comment: Yes, sorry for not updating you guys, but it works fine in WinXP, but it doesn't matter which installation of Win7 I put on it, it just simply doesn't work as it should.

Comment: Okay, so the next logical step would be to try a liveboot with windows 7. Preferably using your copy of win7
This seems viable
https://www.raymond.cc/blog/useful-emergency-bootable-cdusb-wondershare-liveboot-2012-for-free/
or this one
https://www.technorms.com/8098/create-windows-7-live-cd
If your problem is not replicable using your win7 on a liveboot pendrive you can rule out win7 corruption. And I would start to consider hardware issues. Perhaps the hard drive.

Comment: Ok, I just replaced my mouse and it seems to work fine now... It's just weird  seeing how driver doesn't like certain applications.